Anyway to have a Markdown template?
I have a knowledge content I need to store in a github repo. The content is around 40 files (right now in 40 docx). They're all pretty much a one-page file. They have a common structure:

Problem
Some blurb
Options
some blurb
Recommendation
Some blurb

If I write down 40 md files (copy/paste the structure and fill in blurbs), I risk dealing later with the issue of structure needing a slight change - for example Renaming "Recommendation" to "Solution", or some other formatting details. I'd have to touch 40 files just for formatting.
There must be a better way.
For example, is there a way to define the template of the md file in one place, and then create the 40 md files that hold the content but in a way that is not necessarily formatted. Then have something that renders those files using the template?

Would it be possible for you to use a markdown grid instead or would the content be too big for the cells ?

Thanks for the thought, but the content would be large sometimes. Plus, working with markdown tables is a nightmare to be honest with large content (you know, the pipes and all). HTML table is another option, but I'm trying to go the router of having mini digestible md files for each record.

Maybe I am overthinking and overengineering this. The more I think about it, the more I realize what I'm asking is probably not worth doing. If the structure changes eventually, whatever solution there is, it'll have to change in many places anyways. AI gave me a proposal to have an md file template with placeholders, and a python script to read the structure content from a json, and the script generates the md files. I just think it's probably not worth it since the 40-page content would need to be maintained in json files.

Seems a bit too complicated yes, too bad Markdown doesn't seem to have templating.


I risk dealing later with the issue of structure needing a slight change - for example Renaming "Recommendation" to "Solution", or some other formatting details. I'd have to touch 40 files just for formatting.

You will always need to pick a certain structure for your data.
The idea of templating is to separate presentation from data. Any templating solution will need to read its data from some data format (e.g. JSON) and there you will have to define your key-names as well. Whether you have:

a JSON field "recommendation":,
a markdown heading ## Recommendation, or
a HTML heading <h2>Recommendation</h2>

It doesn't matter. In all three formats you need to choose the field-name (recommendation in this case) and define a structure (even if you don't enforce it with a schema or validator, the structure is still there for the data to be useful). And in all three cases you can later write a script to automatically change the name of the field or heading.
Thus I would argue you indeed don't gain anything from going beyond the markdown file you already have.
